# Django core serializers, full path of image or method serialize

Tags: django, serialization

I have simply model:

```
class SimplyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True)

    def get_image(self):
        return self.image.path

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And I serilize it by

```
from django.core import serializers

def get_my_model(request):
    #some operations...
    data = serializers.serialize('json', SimplyModel.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(
        data,
        content_type="application/json"
    )
```

But on frontend when I service this data, in image filed I have only:

```
images/myimage.jpg
```

without media prefix.

I have all 'media-configuration'

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "../media")
```

And I can get this image by serveradress.com/media/images/myimage.jpg

I tried to add method to model, like

```
def get_image(self):
    return self.image.path
```

But I cannot see this method in my respons.

How can I get this absolute path? Or serilize method by django-core serialzer? (I don't want to use DRF)

Best

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add a method to your model to get the url.
Just access it in your template by using the built in .url method.

Example of how it works:

```
obj = SimplyModel.objects.get(pk=123)
url = obj.image.url
```